# How to add custom emote icon?

Tags: android, android-studio, chat, emoji, instant-messaging

I am trying to create an android instant messaging app for a school. So I had downloaded Telegram's app code from github.I was wondering how I could add more emote icons to it, so that I could make few new sets of icons and add it to the existing ones. Or can you tell me how to add custom emoji's to the code.

I couldn't find any tutorial online.

Comment: save the icons on server use reference to download show to user. :)

Comment: @Muthu How can I do that sir?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should upload your code, so we can see what it is about.
   Also provide a link to download the project from github.
2. You also need to know the basic of Photoshop. If you want to
       create custom icons you rreally need to know how thinks work.

Comment: https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram
This is the github link to telegram's code, I have not done much changes to it yet, so you can see the code from here.

Yes, I do know photoshop well. I do not know how to add the emote icons to the code, I was asking how I could add it..

Answer (score 0):

you can find the Emoji's Map, and extend it with your Emojis, Entry Should look like: 
 sEmojisMap.put(0x1f354, R.drawable.emoji_1f354);
it's little complex to deal with . but this link mey help:
https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/rockerhieu/emojicon

Comment: Hello sir, how do I extend it with my emoji's, are there any examples that I could use to see how that is done..